# ng2 translate - get value from function in pipe

Tags: angular

I use ng2-translate for the i18n support in a angular2 project.
Is there a way to get the value from a function and using the translate pipe?

I would like to do something like :

```
{{'text' | translate:'{value: getWorld()}'}}
```

translate.json:

```
{
    "text": "hello {{value}}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible right now, but that's something that could be possible in the future, I'd have to update the lib for that though. Or you can make a PR :)